# cygwin in win 7 bit bash commands

Tags: git, intellij-idea, cygwin

I use Intellij-idea in windows7 and I want to run and work on my project on Cygwin.
I installed Cygwin and now I have just Cygwin terminal.
I add to environment variables under path

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;
C:\cygwin64\bin;
C:\maven\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

when i do

```
git checkout MYBRANCH
git status
git commit -m "note"
```

it work.
but when i do

```
git push origin MYBRANCH
```

in the current window create new line (like thinking) but nothing happened
so i can not do push

and when i try to do clean or install i get this error

```
$ mvn clean
/cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn: line 20: $'\r': command not found
/cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn: line 36: $'\r': command not found
/cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn: line 53: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn: line 53: `case "`uname`" in
```

the file mvn: in line 20 and 36 i have blank line.
and in 53 :

```
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN*) cygwin=true ;;
  MINGW*) mingw=true;;
  Darwin*) darwin=true
```

please your help
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, `dos2unix mvn mvn` worked for me.

Comment: `dos2unix mvn mvn` or `dos2unix mvn` ? Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

\r is a carriage return, which is part of DOS' [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) representation.  You'll have to convert the file to Unix line endings. it would appear you can use [tr](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html) within cygwin to do so (code from second link):

```
tr -d '\15\32' < winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin works with *line feeds* (\n) while Windows works with *carriage return line feeds* (\r\n).

In Intellij there is a **line separator dropdown** in the status bar at the bottom right reading `CRLF`. Switch it to `LF` and run your script again.

[image: Intellij line seperator at the bottom right]

You can also change the line separators via `File` > `Line Separators`

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-line-separators.html

Additionally you can disable the checkout as CRLF feature by setting `autocrlf = false` in your git config or via git bash:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```